# Postgrex how to define json library

Tags: json, elixir, ecto, postgrex

I'm just trying to use Postgrex without any kind of ecto setup, so just the example from the documentation readme.

Here is what my module looks like:

```
defmodule Receive do

  def start(_type, _args) do
    {:ok, pid} = Postgrex.start_link(
      hostname: "localhost",
      username: "john",
      # password: "",
      database: "property_actions",
      extensions: [{Postgrex.Extensions.JSON}]
    )
    Postgrex.query!(
      pid,
      "INSERT INTO actions (search_terms) VALUES ($1)",
      [
        %{foo: 'bar'}
      ]
    )

  end
end
```

when I run the code I get

```
** (RuntimeError) type `json` can not be handled by the types module Postgrex.DefaultTypes, it must define a `:json` library in its options to support JSON types
```

Is there something I'm not setting up correctly? From what I've gathered in the documentation, I shouldn't even need to have that extensions line because json is handled by default.

Comment: Try adding this to `config/config.exs`: `config :postgrex, :json_library, Poison`.

Comment: `extensions: [{Postgrex.Extensions.JSON}]` ⇒ `extensions: [{Postgrex.Extensions.JSON, library: Poison}]` should help.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ Use [`Jason`](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/readme.html) by @michalmuskala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Postgrex <= 0.13, you need to define your own types:

```
Postgrex.Types.define(MyApp.PostgrexTypes, [], json: Poison)
```

and then when starting Postgrex:

```
Postgrex.start_link(types: MyApp.PostgrexTypes)
```

On Postgrex >= 0.14 (currently master), it was made easier:

```
config :postgrex, :json_library, Poison
```